# How to change Span text with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am trying to change text using javascript, but I can't target this element no matter what...

```
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-2d85236 elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="2d85236" data-element_type="widget" id="is_connected" data-settings="{&quot;ekit_we_effect_on&quot;:&quot;none&quot;}" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
            <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                <div class="elementor-text-editor elementor-clearfix"><p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ff0000;">Not Connected</span></p></div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

I want to change this "Not Connected" to "Connected"
I tried with this, but it doesn't work:

```
var AddressText = $("#connect").html(address.substr(0, 13) + "...")
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(elementor-element elementor-element-2d85236 elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor)[0].innerText;
    elems = "Connected"
```

Comment: Use `innerHTML` instead of `innerText`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the selector inside `'`

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('elementor-element elementor-element-2d85236 elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor')[0].innerText = 'connected'
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let spanTag = document.querySelector('.elementor-clearfix p').childNodes[1];
spanTag.innerHTML = 'Connetcted';
```

```html
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-2d85236 elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="2d85236" data-element_type="widget" id="is_connected" data-settings="{&quot;ekit_we_effect_on&quot;:&quot;none&quot;}" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div class="elementor-text-editor elementor-clearfix">
      <p style="text-align: center;">
        <span style="color: #ff0000;">Not Connected</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
let spanTag = document.querySelector('.elementor-text-editor elementor-clearfix')[1];
spanTag.innerHTML = 'connected';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you can try :

```
   var elems = "Connected"
   var AddressText = document.getElementsByClassName('elementor-element elementor-element-2d85236 elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor')[0].innerText = elems
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `textContent` to update the text

```
document.getElementsByClassName('elementor-element elementor-element-2d85236 elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor')[0].textContent = "Connected"
```